# Ajax Json can't access results

Tags: ajax, json, mootools

I am making a json call via ajax (using mootools).  It works fine and returns the json object:

holdingArray
    [Object { id="3", gpname="Mrs make you better", created_by="493", more...}

(copied from firebug)

I have some code to try to access the object but I can't get it to work:

```
 onComplete: function(jsonObj) {
   alert("gp name is "+jsonObj[0].gpname);
   ...
```

It says jsonObj[0].gpname is undefined.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I solved it!!

just wasn't addressing the object correctly.  Should be:

```
 alert("gp name is "+jsonObj.holdingArray[0]['gpname']);
```

which takes the hodlingArray object 0 and then the name

simple when you know how - very frustrating when you can't solve it :)